# sheerun/vim-polyglot ruby seems cause enormous slow down, how to fix or better plugin to use?

Tags: neovim, performance, filetype-ruby, plugin-vim-polyglot

When I open a ruby based file (`.rb,.erb`) in nvim, it causes my whole laptop to slow down!

This seems to be caused by `sheerun/vim-polyglot` that I use for syntax highlighting, specifically the ruby module.

Any one have a better option or a way to fix this?

[nvim config](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/tree/master/tag-config/config/nvim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if ruby path is not set correctly during vim compilation, it slows down vim when editing ruby files, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141652/5586914).

Also, using old regex engine (`set re=1`) rather than the new one speed things up apparently.

Comment: Whilst this didn't completly solve the issue, it did noticeably speed things up! Specifically I used: `let g:ruby_path = system('echo $HOME/.rbenv/shims')` to manually set the ruby path so I wouldn't have to re-compile neovim. I'll set this as the answer as this does explain the issue and provide a partial solution (maybe a complete one?).